# Update Subscription in Stripe Payments in php

Tags: stripe-payments

Why i can't update Subscription?

```
$cus = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($stripeCustomerId);
$subscription=$cus->subscriptions->retrieve($cus->subscriptions->data[0]->id);
$subscription->plan = "1";
$subscription->save();
```

What's wrong in my code my i cant update Subscription?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Not showing any error,but cant update Subscription

Comment: then you should try to enable php error logging, or read through your error logs